# Hibernate/JPA: Get one (first) element of a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a OneToMany relationship, let's say `ListGroup` owns many `ListItem`s.  I have the OneToMany field defined and it works, but I don't always want to get all the `ListItem`s.  I want an additional field called `latestItem`.  In Hibernate, when you access one element in the oneToMany collection it fetches all of them, which is why I want this additional mapping.  If there are many items, the following is inefficient:

```
public ListItem getFirstItem() {
    return listItems.get(0);
}
```

I tried to set up a formula.  Formulas seem to work if I want to fetch a single column of the related field, like this:

```
@Formula("(select A.description from LIST_ITEM A where A.list_group_id=id and A.id=(select max(B.id) from LIST_ITEM B where B.list_group_id=id))")
public String getLatestListItemDescription() { ... }
```

However, if I try to select the whole row to be put in a bean, it fails:

```
@Formula("(select A.* from LIST_ITEM A where A.list_group_id=id and A.id=(select max(B.id) from LIST_ITEM B where B.list_group_id=id))")
public ListItem getLatestListItem() { ... }

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ListItem, at table: LIST_GROUP, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Formula( (select A.* from LIST_ITEM A where A.list_group_id=id and A.id=(select max(B.id) from LIST_ITEM B where B.list_group_id=id)) )]
```

Even though I have annotations for ListItem which map it to the LIST_ITEM table.

Is this not possible with Formulas or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably should use `select A from LIST_ITEM A` instead of `select A.* from LIST_ITEM A`.

p.s. lol I'm late a bit